# How to make my hyperlink selected in html page

Tags: html

There is language link that show the language list. 
If you click the specific language the language level will be displayed button of the language. 
After selecting the language it will redirect and show the result.
The result is appear but i want to make the language and the language level clicked as selected.
I am using "ul" "li" tags. 
can someone help me to make the links selected?
what property can i use in my "a" tag?

This is the html code for that part

```
<tr class="language">
                <th><span>语言水平：</span></th>
                <td id="selectmenu">
                    <ul class="tabs4 language_list">
                        <li><a href="#">全部</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">中文</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">日语</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">英语</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tabs_content4 language_content">
                        <div class="all"></div>
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">母语水</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">商务水</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">日常会话</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">简单会话</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">母语水</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">商务水</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">日常会话</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">简单会话</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">母语水</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">商务水</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">日常会话</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">简单会话</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">母语水</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">商务水</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">日常会话</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">简单会话</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post your code you done so far.

Comment: In stack overflow, we need to see what the asker has tried, so you might want to give us the codes and I'm not quite understanding the question but I think this job is for PHP

Comment: Why are you using a table for this? Consider changing to a native form select. It can be styled using a plugin like: http://code.octopuscreative.com/fancyselect/

Comment: this table is inside the form